# Is there any similar way to handle hiding endpoints from swagger documentation?

Tags: c#, rest, swagger-2.0

I found below link to hide endpoints in swagger documentation. I want to achieve this with Swashbuckle code to hide endpoints from swagger documentation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-swagger-hiding-endpoints

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Rama